# Reductio Ad Absurdum

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

This is a riddle with diminishing returns.
It's acrostic again. Can't kick that habit.
No special knowledge is needed.
When you find the answer, you will be in no doubt.

> Faker! They cried and cut off his tail.
>   Call for the axe, put his head in a pail
>   Sharpen the axe and take off his top
>   Single him out, let him endlessly drop
>   Atop the trash heap. Take his last right away.
>   Nothing left. Now we're done. Goodbye and good day.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is

> PHONEY $~\to~$ PHONE $~\to~$ HONE $~\to~$ ONE $~\to~$ ON $~\to~$ O

### Argument:

Faker! They cried and cut off his tail.

> A faker is PHONEY; cutting of the tail Y yields PHONE

Call for the axe, put his head in a pail

> You do calls with your PHONE; cutting of the head P yields HONE

Sharpen the axe and take off his top

> To HONE is another word for to sharpen; taking of the top H yields ONE

Single him out, let him endlessly drop

> The ONE is singled out; dropping the end E yields ON

Atop the trash heap. Take his last right away.

> Atop is ON; taking the right N away leaves O

Nothing left. Now we're done. Goodbye and good day.

> O or 0 or zero stands for nothing

Comment: Congratulations! I fear it must have been too easy for you. I'll be vaguer next time. ;)

Comment: It was not too easy.  The "faker" gave me SWINDLER or FRAUD or PHONY/PHONEY, and "sharpen" gave me WHET or HONE.

Comment: Acrostics can go by letter, syllable or word. In this case the first word of each line. They don't exactly form a message but I wasn't sure what else to call it.

Comment: I see. Beautiful!